# What effects do the cheat codes have in addition to their actions?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

Currently the game has a bug that can prevent unlocking the next mission in the campaign, usage of [cheat codes](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=186760017) could be considered mandatory in this case. For example, does the game mark the save file as "cheats enabled" or disable statistics and achievements after the player has entered a cheat code for the current game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [achievement guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=251594152), you will not be able to unlock any achievements if you activate cheats.

> If you use these cheats you will not get any achievements.