# How to fix the campaign progress bug (missions not unlocking)?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

There a [widely known bug](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/search/?q=missions%20unlock) in Age of Empires II: HD Edition which causes subsequent campaign missions not to unlock. The issue can be bypassed by starting a new game and using [cheat codes](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?l=english&id=186760017) to unlock levels, but cheats [disable at least achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/301659/148510) and the method is highly inconvenient to use as missions have to be treated in chronological order. I encountered this glitch early on and expect that the incident isn't necessarily a one-off occurrence.

Is there an alternative solution?

---

At the time of writing the bug hasn't been fixed ([all patch notes](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/announcements/)).

Comment: Unless they've patched it, I've gotten the campaign completion achievements by using cheats and then beating a random map game

Comment: @BenCraig: Do you mean finishing not-completed levels after using cheats? That's good to know.

Comment: Er, I mean I got the campaign achievements by beating the campaign with cheats, and then when I played a normal game I got the campaign achievement

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your current profile and make a new one, that's the only fix I know. You can use the "i r winner" cheat to quickly go back where you were before. **Don't worry**, if you completed every single level without cheat, you will get the achievements (worked for me). Just i r winner those missions/campaigns that you already done before.

Comment: This is not new information, I told about cheats in the question.

Comment: @user598527 I believe the user is saying that cheats only disable achievements for the current level, aka if you use the "I r winner" cheat to get up to the level that failed to unlock you'd still get achievements for beating it

Comment: Sorry if I have misunderstood!

Comment: Deleting the profile may not be necessary now.